# Can we read a property from application.property file in manifist.yml file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

In my spring-boot app,I have a property called `version` in my `application.properties` file and i want to use it in my `manifest.yml` file.

In my `application.properties`

```
version=v1
```

I tried using below in my manifest file

App

```
name :xyz-${version}
```

but when i start my app it failed saying

> cannot resolve version

Answer (score 0):

`Application.properties` and `mainfest.yml` are the same but they are just in different data formats you can read their properties in java files but not in one another like you said.

[Here's](https://meetsnehal.wordpress.com/2015/09/12/yaml-an-alternative-to-properties-file-with-spring-boot/) is a blog and [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings) related to yaml.